# How do I enable TPM in the BIOS?

Tags: bios, tpm

I have a new motherboard (Asus Sabertooth Z87) which cliams to support TPM. However, when I attempt to enable TPM - I don't see an appropriate setting in the BIOS. 
Obviously I'm looking for something like "TPM: Enable/Disable" :) - perhaps there's another name for this setting? or perhaps I need to do something else before the setting reveals itself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah, looks like this motherboard comes with a TPM *header*. I think I need to buy and fit a TPM chip - then something should light up in the BIOS.

Asus tech support confirmed this is the case. I need one of these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module

Comment: Installing the TMP chip caused the option to light up in the BIOS. 
It works!

Comment: Link is dead...

Comment: It sure is.
Changed it to link to a generic page about TPMs.
Make sure you buy one that's compatible with your motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

To enable you just have to read the BIOS option carefully.

After entering the BIOS, visit the *Security* tab and then set the TPM enabled or disabled.